# Python - Google Colab - IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, if-statement, sparse-matrix, truthtable

I am trying to solve the sparse matrix equation

```
u_derivative_1 = A * u
```

(A is the sparse matrix)

But I'm getting the following error :-

> ```
>   IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>   <ipython-input-24-f4af80e4ae52> in <cell line: 1>()
>   ----> 1 trial1 = discretise_delta_u_v4(1000, 'implicit')
>   <ipython-input-23-731d13e4ddf7> in discretise_delta_u_v4(N, method)
>        61         for i in range (1 , N-1):
>        62           for j in range (1 , N-1):
>   ---> 63             A[i,j] = (u[i-1,j] + u[i+1,j] + u[i,j-1] + u[i,j+1] - (4*u[i,j]))/(h**2)
>        64 
>   IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
> ```

I am confused why I am getting this error and how to resolve this. This is my code -

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.sparse
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

def discretise_delta_u_v4(N, method):

    i = np.arange(0,N)
    j = np.arange(0,N)
    h = 2/N

    A = csr_matrix((N, N), dtype = np.float64).toarray()
    u = np.array([[(i*h), (j*h)]])

    #u[ih,jh] = 
    u[:,0] = 5    #Boundary
    u[:,-1] = 0   #Boundary
    u[0,:] = 0    #Boundary
    u[-1,:] = 0   #Boundary

    #Implicit
    if (method=='implicit') :
        A[0,:] = 0
        A[-1,:] = 0
        A[:,0] = 0
        A[:,-1] = 0
        for i in range (1 , N-1):
          for j in range (1 , N-1):
            A[i,j] = (u[i-1,j] + u[i+1,j] + u[i,j-1] + u[i,j+1] - (4*u[i,j]))/(h**2)

    # u_der_1 = A * u
    for i in range (0 , N):
      for j in range (0 , N):
        u_der_1 = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A,u)


trial1 = discretise_delta_u_v4(1000, 'implicit')
```

Comment: replace `A = csr_matrix((N, N), dtype = np.float64).toarray()`  with direct `A=np.zeros((N,N))`.   It's easier to get code working for a modest size dense array, and later convert to sparse.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing specifically is being caused by the way you're constructing the array `u`.

Doing `u = np.array([[(i*h), (j*h)]])` results in `u` being:

```
[[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.], [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

which is an array of shape (1, 2, 10). Therefore, when you do `u[i+1,j]` the only valid value of `i+1` is 0, everything else is out of bounds.

Given the problem you are trying to solve, there are a few more issues with the approach.

1. You want A to be a sparse matrix, but you're creating it as a dense matrix by converting it to a dense array (i.e. `A = csr_matrix((N, N), dtype = np.float64).toarray()`). You should remove the call to `.toarray()`.
2. You're also initialising `u` incorrectly, you want a 1-dimensional array of `N**2` elements, instead you're initialising a 2D array.
3. You have `u_der_1 = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A,u)` inside a loop, which is also not correct. You need to build the matrix A first and then solve the system.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix

def discretise_delta_u_v4(N, method):
    
    # Initialise the matrix A as a list of lists first
    h = 2 / N
    A = lil_matrix((N ** 2, N ** 2), dtype=np.float64)

    if method == 'implicit':
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                index = i * N + j
                if i == 0 or i == N - 1 or j == 0 or j == N - 1:
                    A[index, index] = 1
                else:
                    A[index, index] = -4 / (h ** 2)
                    A[index, index - 1] = 1 / (h ** 2)
                    A[index, index + 1] = 1 / (h ** 2)
                    A[index, index - N] = 1 / (h ** 2)
                    A[index, index + N] = 1 / (h ** 2)

    A = A.tocsr(). # You conver to a CSR matrix here

    u = np.zeros(N ** 2)
    u[0:N] = 5  # Per your boundary condition

    u_der_1 = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A, u)
    return u_der_1.reshape(N, N)

trial1 = discretise_delta_u_v4(10, 'implicit')
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help and for pointing out the mistakes. I have a few doubts in your solution - (1) what is the list_of_lists_matrix() and the u_flat here?  (2)  Why have you taken (i*N)+j and then writing A[index,index] instead of th eway I had written it? Why did you make the change here?..

Comment: Hi. I fixed the variable name there, I had renamed `u` to `u_flat` to make it clearer that I was talking about a flat array then thought it'd add confusion and reverted it. Guess I left it in one place. As for the list_of_lists_matrix, my bad, I wrote it from memory, the method is actually called lil_matrix, you can import it from scipy, I added the imports to the answer.

Comment: As for your second question: you're directly assigning values to the matrix using 2D indexing. This might work well for small matrixes, but it's not efficient for large ones, hence the change to 1D indexing. Also, for handling boundary conditions, you're assigning the entire first and last rows to zero, which can lead to a singular matrix. Also modifying the CSR directly in a loop is not very efficient, starting with a LIL is more efficient for incremental changes, then converting to CSR.